# Simplification of a recursive linear algebra system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, recursion

I've come across a problem that can be described by the following system:
$$C_n=I-B_{n-1}^2$$
$$B_n=A_{n-1}C^{-1}_n B_{n-1} A_{n-1} + B_{n-1}$$
$$A_n=A_{n-1}C^{-1}_n A_{n-1}$$

Where $A$ and $B$ are square, non-symmetric, dense matrices. $A_0$ and $B_0$ are available and the necessary output are $A_n$ and $B_n$ for a specific $n$.

Currently, $A_n$ and $B_n$ are obtained by solving the system, with the inverse of $C_n$ being explicitly calculated (no factorization). As expected, the solution takes a long time.

I have two questions:

1. Is there any obvious algebraic manipulation that I'm missing that could significantly simplify the system?
2. If instead of directly calculating the inverse of $C_n$, its factorization was used, could it be reused in the system for a faster solution?

Comment: I would like to know the origin of your problem. It is *much* more interesting than I first thought. Moreover, there appears to be a small speed advantage to work with equations satisfied by the transposed matrices.

Comment: @CarlChristian Well, the method found at http://omlc.org/~prahl/pubs/pdf/prahl95c.pdf (eqs. 5.29 & 5.30) is the basis for this problem. I would love to hear any additional thoughts you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unless further assumptions are added, I don't see any real possibilities. Ex. if $A_{n-1}$ and $B_{n-1}$ can be simultaneously diagonalized, then this property carries inductively to $A_n$ and $B_n$ via $C_n$, and the complexity of each subsequent step is linear in the matrix dimension. However, we are not likely to encounter this situation outside of a textbook. A more realistic assumption is that your matrices are hierarchical matrices for which fast multiplication and inversion routines are known.
2. For numerical reasons, we should avoid forming $C_n$ explicitly, unless we actually need to examine some entries. I do not see a way to reduce the flop count, but we can try to maximize the potential for BLAS3 operations, i.e., matrix matrix multiplication. You obtain an LU factorization of $C_n$ using, say, DGETRF (real double precision arithmetic, Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting) from LAPACK. You need $X_n = C_{n}^{-1}A_{n-1}$ and $Y_n = C_n^{-1} B_{n-1}$. You obtain them by solving the system $$C_n \begin{bmatrix} X_n & Y_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A_{n-1} & B_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$ using, say, DGETRS (forward/backward substitution using the output of DGETRF) from LAPACK. This subroutine overwrites the original RHS with the solution, so you must begin each iteration by making a copy, say, $$\begin{bmatrix} Z_1 & Z_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A_{n-1} & B_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}.$$ You then multiply with $Z_1 = A_{n-1}$ from the left to produce
   $$\begin{bmatrix} A_{n-1} X_n & A_{n-1} Y_n \end{bmatrix} =
   \begin{bmatrix} A_{n-1} C_n^{-1} A_{n-1} & A_{n-1} C_n^{-1} B_{n-1}
   \end{bmatrix},$$
   using DGEMM from BLAS. You now have $A_n$ and $B_n$ can be computed with a single DGEMM operation. Organizing the calculations in this manner does not change the flop count, but increases the opportunity for the machine to use matrix matrix operations. They have high arithmetic intensity (large number of flops per memory operation), hence they are well suited for machines with deep memory hierarchies, and they are also well suited for SIMD operations.
3. Comment/question: It seems to me that you must have some assumptions on $B_0$ to preclude the case of, say, $$B_0 = \begin{bmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & X \end{bmatrix},$$ where $I_r$ is the identity matrix of dimension $r$ and $X$ is any suitably size dense matrix. Otherwise, $C_0$ has singular.

Comment: Why not use $A_{n-1}C_n^{-1}=(C_n^{-T}A_{n-1}^T)^T$ as the intermediate result in step 2?

Comment: @Lutzl: Your approach *will* reduce the number of flops. However, when solving $C_n^T R_n = A_{n-1}^T$ using DGETRS we need to transpose $A_{n-1}$ in memory. Doing this efficiently, i.e., without a large number of cache misses, is *not* a trivial thing to program. If a good transposition routine is available, then one can give it a try, but one should not waste time transposing $R_n$, Instead flags should be used to indicate transposition when doing calls to DGEMM. I aimed for a solution which would have stride 1 access of memory.